# django filter can't find a right solution

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

my models:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="order_user")
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(_('e-mail'))
    address = models.CharField(_('address'), max_length=250)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class OrderItem(models.Model):
   id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
   order = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name='items', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='order_items', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   shop = models.ForeignKey(MyShop, related_name='shop_order', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
   quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
```

my views:

```
def shop_orders(request):
    order = Order.objects.filter(items__shop=request.user.user_profile_shop)
    return render(request, 'account/paneli/shop/orders/shop_orders.html', {'order': order,})
```

in the template,it show the order of the shop but it shows the OrderItem of all the shops

```
{% for order in order  %}
    order.id #it ok  
    {% for item in order.items.all %}
      
        {{ item.product }}# wrong shows the OrderItem of all the shops
       
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

can you help me someone where i went wrong

the order has the products of many stores, I want to filter the order only with the products of the current shop

Comment: What is the `ManagerOrder` doing?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I had some things wrong,   I edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) with [`Prefetch()` objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-objects) to filter on the related objects (plus this makes it more efficient by solving the N + 1 problem):

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch


def shop_orders(request):
    orders = Order.objects.prefetch_related(
        Prefetch(
            'items',
            queryset=OrderItem.objects.filter(shop=request.user.user_profile_shop).select_related('shop'),
            to_attr='items_from_specific_shop'
        )
    )
    return render(request, 'account/paneli/shop/orders/shop_orders.html', {'orders': orders,})
```

Then in the template you can write:

```
{% for order in orders %}
    order.id
    {% for item in order.items_from_specific_shop %}      
        {{ item.product }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hi @Abdul Aziz Barkat,i add this new line, do you know some way to calculate the ord_total, have the total sum of all object in order

Comment: @GuianaAnnimali edits (especially to _answers_) are not meant for asking new questions. If you have a new question please ask it separately.

Answer (score 0):

user reverse query using related name in shop field in order_item

```
def shop_orders(request):
    order = Order.objects.filter(items__shop=request.user.user_profile_shop)
    shop = current_shop#get a shop whose items you need
    
    order_for_shop = shop.shop_order.all()
    return render(request, 'account/paneli/shop/orders/shop_orders.html', {'order': order_for_shop,})
```